# How to pass table as input parameter to Web Service?

Tags: wsdl, progress-4gl, openedge

I am invoking methods of WSDL in Progress Openedge. So far i don't have problems invoking "GET" methods where i just need to pass password. The problem is when i need to use "SET" methods which needs password + some data stored in temp-tables. So far i have searched and found nothing that could help me. 
Below is code which works for calling GET methods.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hWebService             AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hServiceSoap     AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE symbol                  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE resp                 AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

define variable xmlCHar as longchar no-undo.

CREATE SERVER hWebService.
hWebService:CONNECT("-WSDL 'url_of_my_wsdl'").
IF NOT hWebService:CONNECTED() THEN DO:
MESSAGE "SERVER: " SKIP "url_of_my_wsdl" SKIP
                  "is not connected"
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
RETURN.
END.

RUN GET_smth_or_SET_smth SET hServiceSoap ON hWebService.

IF NOT VALID-HANDLE(hServiceSoap) THEN DO:
MESSAGE "PortType: " VALID-HANDLE(hServiceSoap) " is not valid"
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
    RETURN.
END.

/* password/key */
symbol = "1234asasdas".

RUN SetERPSavedStatus IN hServiceSoap(INPUT symbol, OUTPUT resp).

IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
  DEFINE VARIABLE iCnt AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
  DO iCnt = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:
      MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(iCnt)
          VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
  END.

  IF VALID-HANDLE(ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL) THEN DO:
     DEFINE VARIABLE hXML        AS HANDLE     NO-UNDO.
     DEFINE VARIABLE mDoc        AS MEMPTR     NO-UNDO.
     CREATE X-DOCUMENT hXML.
     hXML:LOAD('LONGCHAR', ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL:SOAP-FAULT-DETAIL:GET-SERIALIZED(), FALSE).
 hXML:SAVE("memptr", mDoc).
 MESSAGE "Fault Code  : " ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL:SOAP-FAULT-CODE  SKIP
            "Fault String: " ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL:SOAP-FAULT-STRING SKIP
            "Fault Actor : " ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL:SOAP-FAULT-ACTOR SKIP
            "Error Type  : " ERROR-STATUS:ERROR-OBJECT-DETAIL:TYPE  SKIP SKIP
            "Fault Detail: " SKIP GET-STRING(mDoc,1)
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
  END.
END.

/* display of respond*/
MESSAGE resp
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

    DELETE OBJECT hServiceSoap.
    hWebService:DISCONNECT().
    DELETE OBJECT hWebService.
```

What do i need to change/improve to send with my password data in temp table? When i run this code for GET methods, it works. When i use it for SET methods then i get message 
[image]

Any help would be nice.

**UPDATE**

I changed code from

```
RUN SetERPSavedStatus IN hServiceSoap(INPUT symbol, OUTPUT resp)
to 
RUN SetERPSavedStatus IN hServiceSoap(INPUT symbol, INPUT param, OUTPUT resp)
```

since i realized that that method have 2 input parameters, 1st is string, 2nd is string-array. And now the error is

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Input params are next (WSDL)

```
<s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="key" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ids" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>
</s:sequence>
```

Ouput response is

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Result" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>
```

In Progress, i have also 3 params (2 input and 1 output). Tried to combine with types of string/integer/handle and nothing works. Still same error. I tried to test method  in [Boomerang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah) and it works there, so it's not the problem about the method.

In this app i call this method with request

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:izv="http://link...">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <izv:nameOfMethod>
        <izv:key>123abcdwqsad112312</izv:key>
        <izv:ids>
            <izv:int>1</izv:int>
            <izv:int>2</izv:int>
            <izv:int>3</izv:int>
            <izv:int>3108</izv:int>
            <izv:int>5</izv:int>
            <izv:int>6</izv:int>
            <izv:int>7</izv:int>
            <izv:int>3070</izv:int>
            <izv:int>8</izv:int>
        </izv:ids>
    </izv:nameOfMethod>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Response of that request is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <nameOfMethodResponse xmlns="http://link...">
        <nameOfMethodResult>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>1</int>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>0</int>
            <int>1</int>
            <int>0</int>
        </nameOfMethodResult>
    </nameOfMethodResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? This Progress documentation shows how to pass tables around using webservices:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvwsv/invoking-a-method-with-a-table-parameter.html#wwconnect_header

Comment: Another thought: Have you tried messaging the resulting XML to the screen or outputting it to a file? It may just be malformed, as the message states.

Comment: I tried to message the result in code. Check "/* display of respond*/" area in code.

Comment: @bupereira i updated my code with additional data

Comment: Ok, but what is the type of param in its definition? If it's a string-array, it should probably be an extent character variable.
Also, can you post the header to the setERPSavedStatus, if you have access to it?
And finally, I saw you're messaging it, but you don't know what it is, right? Are you hitting the error before you can see what the resulting xml is?

Comment: In WSDL file that param is StringArray. In my code that param is defined as `define variable param as character EXTENT 40 no-undo. `. I don't have access to message because it hits error before i want to display it.

Comment: Fine, and how about the output parameter type? Is it supposed to be Character, too? That signature error looks a lot like it's just a type problem you're hitting... if you can pass that, you'll most likely start getting responses, at least.

Comment: I also found this, this guy said there was a parameter he was unaware about: 
https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_development/f/19/t/2428

Comment: @bupereira i'v updated my question with additional data. Have tried to add more input params than it's in wsdl config, tried to change types of input params and still don't work.

Comment: Is this the signature to the method you're trying to call? It seems to me it takes a regular character, an integer extent and returns an integer extent as well.

Comment: I have one other method which got string and integer extent as input and integer as output method and it works. So the problem is when i get ouput as integer extent and can't read that. Is it maybe problem because i got it `like <int>0</int> <int>0</int>` and int is maybe reserved word?

Comment: What version are you on? Here's something about a bug regarding arryas in an older release: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P116184

Comment: I'm on 10.2B07. version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally input and output parameters when calling SOAP-based web servers are XML-documents. More often than not you will need to handle them as XML-documents withing LONGCHAR-variables and not DATASETS or TEMP-TABLES.

If calling a webservice with simple input/output you might be able to just create matching datasets or temp-tables but I would say that is rare.

First of all you need to run 'bprowsdldoc' with the provided WSDL to get a readable specification out of your webservice.

Basically:

```
proenv> bprowsdldoc mywsdl.wsdl [directory]
```

This will create a set of html-based documentation in "directory". Open up index.html and look at the 'Operation index' (it's in the upper right corner of the document).

There you will see a list of all operations provided by the wsdl. If you click one you will see the basic approach on how it's constructed and how to call it. You will also see some definitions that might or might not help you depending on how complex the input/output data is.

A basic procedure prototype might look like this:

```
PROCEDURE WS_WebserviceName:
  DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER DATASET FOR WS_Indata.
  DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER WS_Outdata AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
END PROCEDURE.
```

You can see various number of inputs/outputs and of various types. But it all comes down to:

```
PROCEDURE WS_WebserviceName:
  DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER InputData  AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER OutputData AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
END PROCEDURE.
```

(XML goes in and XML goes out.)

You need to look at the rest of the documentation (created by bprowsdldoc) or provided examples when it comes to creating the input data and parsing the output data. You should look at the XML documentation here:
https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2743.openedge-11-6-product-documentation

There's basically two ways of working with XML: SAX and DOM. Read the documentation and choose what seems best to you! You could also handle xml just like text but that will most likely lead to problems!

Once your done with creating and parsing xml you will store it in longchar variables and input/output those to the webservice. Something along the way of:

```
RUN MyWebService IN MyWebServicePort (INPUT XMLInput, OUTPUT XmlOutput).
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I have updated my question with (update 2 section). There you can see that i have string and integer extent as input param and integer extent as ouput param. I have one other method which got string and integer extent as input and integer as output method and it works. So the problem is when i get ouput as integer extent and can't read that. Is it maybe problem because i got it like `<int>0</int> <int>0</int>` and int is maybe reserved word?

Comment: int is not a reserved word in the xml... If you run prowsdldoc and post parts of it I might be able to help you further. You should focus on the body-part of the xml, Progress will handle the soap-envelope for you.

Comment: The only difference with those 2 methods is name and output param. 1st method which i can successful invoke has int output param (`<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="nameofMethodResult" type="s:int"/>`)  and second which i can't invoke has int array output param (`<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nameofMethodResult" type="tns:ArrayOfInt"/>`).  Everything else is the same. In Progress, i call this as `(character,int extent, character)` and in first function i get result successful, and on second method i get error "Cannot match signature..."

Comment: Have you run the bprowsdldoc? It will translate from wsdl-format to a more Progress like format! That documentation should contain a "complete" version of the input xml. Also: you could perhaps look at some example documentation of the web services to see how the input SHOULD look. Also: if the web service is commercial (ie you pay for it) some kind of support is most likely available - perhaps they can give you example input.

Comment: But when i copy that wsdl into wsdl online validator it shows me 0 errors

Comment: If possible contact support!

Comment: Thanks for your help